# Is it possible to perform a hexdump in Lua code

Tags: lua

I'm used to using C but I'm new to Lua. Is there a way to create a Lua program that can read `example.exe` and give me the program's code in hexadecimal?

Comment: `io.open('file.exe', 'rb')`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 So similar to the ifstream command in a sense?

Comment: What a silly question, of course it's possible.

Comment: @Blindy I just keep hearing that its "minimalistic", "stripped down", and "lacks features" so I wasnt sure considering Ive just recently started learning it.

Comment: Your hearing might be going then, because it's one of the most powerful interpreted (or compiled, LuaJIT is a thing) languages in common use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until Lua 5.1, this sample program `xd.lua` was included in the distribution:

```
-- hex dump
-- usage: lua xd.lua < file

local offset=0
while true do
 local s=io.read(16)
 if s==nil then return end
 io.write(string.format("%08X  ",offset))
 string.gsub(s,"(.)",
    function (c) io.write(string.format("%02X ",string.byte(c))) end)
 io.write(string.rep(" ",3*(16-string.len(s))))
 io.write(" ",string.gsub(s,"%c","."),"\n") 
 offset=offset+16
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
local filename = arg[1]

if filename == nil then
  print [=[
Usage: dump <filename> [bytes_per_line(16)]]=]
  return
end

local f = assert(io.open(filename, 'rb'))
local block = tonumber(arg[2]) or 16

while true do
  local bytes = f:read(block)
  if not bytes then return end
  for b in bytes:gmatch('.') do
    io.write(('%02X '):format(b:byte()))
  end
  io.write(('   '):rep(block - bytes:len() + 1))
  io.write(bytes:gsub('%c', '.'), '\n')
end
```

Comment: `xd.lua` was written before the generic `for` and `gmatch` were introduced. Thanks for this modern-looking version of `xd.lua`.